# Path to the GWT Installation Directory

Tags: eclipse, gwt, windowbuilder

I have installed WindowBuilder and I'm trying to create a GWT Java Project in Eclipse Helios. In the "GWT Settings" window, I am instructed to click the "Configure GWT Location" link and point to the path of the GWT installation directory, but I can't seem to find it even though I know WindowBuilder was installed. According to what I've seen online, it should be in the 'plugins' directory in the 'eclipse' folder where I pointed the WindowBuilder download using Eclipse's "Available Software Sites" function.  It's looking for a gwt-user.jar file, but I can't locate such a file even while using Windows Explorer's search function.

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I just went online and searched for the .jar and added it myself. Not sure why it wasn't included in the WindowBuilder download. Anyway, it's working now.

Comment: I just wanted GWT - went plugin route for eclipse Indigo and when I went to create a new "GWT Java Project" I was asked to configure b4 I could continue?? It wanted the gwt-user.jar, so like brohjoe, I downloaded it and it works. But not happy about that.

Comment: Didn't work, can't create project. Click finish button and nothing. :(

Comment: You may use two methods to install GWT SDK -  Eclipse update or install from archive. Refer [GWT Tutorial](https://sites.google.com/site/gwt2tutorial/book/chap-install) for detailed instructions to install GWT SDK in Eclipse Juno

Answer (score 0):

This 2 different things GWT SDK and WindowBuilder both can be installed through Eclipse Update 
but WindowBuilder will not work without the GWT SDK.

the simplest way is to use Google Plugin for Eclipse - http://dl.google.com/eclipse/plugin/3.7 (Eclipse Indigo) select all (or leave out the AppEngine in case you do not need it)
after it installed and eclipse Restarted you are done. 
the "Configure GWT Location" refer to older versions. Now it is not needed.

What you did "works by a miracle" do not go with it I do not know when it will backfire on you with unpredictable behavior.

Comment: Boris, I did exactly what you said above and it gives me the SAME issue... I don't know why but installing plugins from Eclipse is always a nightmare. Any fixes? Does the fact that I have another version of Eclipse sitting at a different directory affect anything?

Comment: go to http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/download.html there click on "Download GWT SDK" download unpack and reference it by clicking the "Configure GWT Location" as instructed

Comment: Three years later...I'm now using Itellij Idea. To me it's a great IDE because I don't have the configuration issues and the tempermental bugginess I had with Eclipse.  Happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

Download GWT SDK manually from http://www.gwtproject.org/download.html, .. unzip it ... you'll fine "gwt-user.jar" there

In Eclipse, open Window | Preferences | Google | Web Toolkit .. click "Add" then browse to this unzipped folder.

You do not need GWT turned on in order to create a New Web Application Project. If you do not want to use GWT just uncheck the "Use Google Web Toolkit" checkbox on that same dialog and it should work.